# Explanation of the terms Pinda, Pada, Rüpa and the Rūpātīta

Tags: shiva, tantra, shakti

In Ullasa 13 of Kaularnava Tantra, verse 76, Shree Shiva says to Shree Devi one of the characteristics of Guru:

> **पिण्डं पदं तथा रूपं रूपातीतं चतुष्टयम** यो वा सम्यग्विजानाति स गुरुः कथितः प्रिये ।। ७६ ।।

> O My Beloved! Who knows well these **Four-the Pinda, Pada, Rüpa and the Rūpātīta,** he is called the Guru.

I have never heard of these four term, and there is no explanation to these in consecutive verses. Do we have any explanation of these 4 term in any other Tantra text?

Comment: In Guru Gita (Skandha Purana we have): श्रीपार्वती उवाच । पिण्डं किं तु महादेव पदं किं समुदाहृतम् ।रूपातीतं च रूपं किं एतदाख्याहि शंकर ॥ Shree Parvati asked: O Lord Mahadeva, please explain these terms to me – What are pinda, pada and rupa? And is there more beyond them? श्रीमहादेव उवाच । पिण्डं कुण्डलिनी शक्तिः पदं हंसमुदाहृतम् ।रूपं बिन्दुरिति ज्ञेयं रूपातीतं निरञ्जनम् ॥ Shree Mahadeva answered: Kundalini Shakti is Pinda, Pada means Hamsa, Rupa is Bindu and Rupatita is Niranjana.

Comment: @Tezz Post that as answer but with more details on Bindu and Niranjana.

Answer (score 0):

From Kashmir Saivism
The Pada (पद) represents one of the four stages of creation corresponding to the Anāhata-cakra, and is explained in terms of kuṇḍalinī by Lakṣmaṇadeśika in his 11th-century Śaradātilaka verse 25.62.—“The ‘solid mass’ (piṇḍa) is doubtlessly the kuṇḍalinī, equivalent to Śiva; the “position” (pada), on the other hand, is doubtlessly the haṃsaḥ, the inner Self of all. The “form” (rūpa) is doubtlessly the bindu of infinite lustre; the blissful union (sāmarasya) with Śiva is “form transcended” (atītarūpa)”.

Note: The terms piṇḍa, pada, rūpa and rūpātīta refer to four stages of creation. These four are also said to correspond to four Cakras: piṇḍa to mūlādhāra, pada to anāhata, rūpa to ājñā and rūpātīta to sahasrāra.